# How can I display a Highcharts organization chart with level 1 nodes below other level 1 nodes?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to set up a simple org chart with Highcharts to display our association board and functions.Below the president, there are 4 level 1 items, then there are 3 folks at level 2 and I would like to add another 5 folks also at level 2 but all this would not fit given the chart width, so I would like to extend the level 2 line so that these 5 level 2 folks get displayed below, pretty much like a level 3...[just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra2u6.png)

I believe that this is easy but just couldn't figure it out...

Thanks for helping out

Philippe

Comment: Instead images next time prepare a demo version of your code or piece of code, it helps understand better your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manipulate properties offsetHorizontal and offsetVertical.

```
  series: [{
    type: 'organization',
    name: 'Digital Transformation',
    keys: ['from', 'to'],
    data: [
      ['CEO', 'Department1'],
      ['CEO', 'Department2'],
      ['CEO', 'Department3'],
      ['CEO', 'Department4'],
      ['CEO', 'Department5'],
      ['CEO', 'Department4x'],
    ],
    levels: [{
      level: 0,
      color: 'silver',
      dataLabels: {
      color: 'white'
      },
      height: 25
    }, {
      level: 1,
      color: 'silver',
      dataLabels: {
      color: 'black'
      },
      height: 25
    }, {
      level: 2,
      color: 'green',
      dataLabels: {
      color: 'black'
      },
      height: 25
    }],
    nodes: [{
      id: '',
      title: 'CEO',
      name: null,
      color: "#000000",
      info: "CEO"
    }, {
      className: 'title',
      id: 'Department1',
      title: 'Department1',
      name: '',
      layout: 'hanging',
    }, {
      id: 'Department2',
      title: 'Department2',
      name: '',
      layout: 'hanging',
    }, {
      id: 'Department3',
      title: 'Department3',
      name: '',
      layout: 'hanging',
    }, {
      id: 'Department4',
      title: 'Department4',
      name: '',
      layout: 'hanging',
    }, {
      id: 'Department5',
      title: 'Department5',
      name: '',
      layout: 'hanging',
      level: 1,
      offsetHorizontal: 15,
      offsetVertical: 0,
    }, {
      id: 'Department4x',
      title: 'Department4x',
      name: '',
      layout: 'hanging',
      level: 2
    }],
  }],
```

Live demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0tk6n94L/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.nodes.offsetHorizontal

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.nodes.offsetVertical

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I'll play with this right now...Sorry for not adding code but what I came up with was so ugly that I did not dare displaying it since I'm absolutely no expert with this language :-)